# Android Studio 3.2: How to remember Android XML code style?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have to go to `Preferences... > Editor > Code Style > XML` to select `Use custom formatting settings for Android XML files` again and again everytime I create a new project.

[image]

I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1, macos 10.14.

Comment: Hey Danh!. I am facing the same problem and I think it is happening because I am using git and I have ignored .idea/ directory. I have tested that if I don't ignore .idea directory then Android studio does remember the last configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own codeStyle:
[image]

Just export your codeStyle to file and use in each project. Or you can `Copy to IDE...` and it will remain in the IDE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It still could not remember the configs.